# django, no sirven mis static 'javascript'

Tags: javascript, html, python, django

No sé que pasa, no puedo cargar mis archivos js dentro de mi `.html`, sin embargo si puedo cargar otros archivos static, en el mismo proyecto tengo cargada varias imagenes de mi directorio static.

El archivo definitivamente sí se encuentra en el path que doy, **sin embargo no lo encuentra.**

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

index.html

```
<!--'extends' crea herencia con plantilla-->
{% extends 'padre.html' %}
{% load static%}
{% block content %}
<!-- aqui todo lo que no se hereda-->
<h2>este es el index</h2>
<script src="{% static 'javascript/main.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock content %}
```

El error que recibo:

```
"GET /static/javascript/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1680
```

Comment: Seria bueno que compartieras tu estructura de carpetas para que pudiéramos verificar si hay algún problema en donde intentas buscar el archivo ya que la mayoría de las veces el problema es en el orden de las carpetas o nombres

Comment: exacto era el problema, pasa algo raro con mi carpeta 'static', por alguna razon se integro con la carpeta 'images' como si fueran una sola, 'static/images' como una sola carpeta, la verdad no se que paso pero ya esta solucionado.